# Order state and status programmatically defined

Tags: magento-2.1

In Magento 2, we can see that there are default order statuses that are assigned to "groups", which are order states.  For example, the "pending" order status is part of the "new" order state group.

Technically speaking or business wise - for and order created programmatically - could it be an issue to assign the order to a sate and status that are not linked by default?

For example would it be an issue to create an order with state "new" and status "processing"?

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Magento uses States to determine where it is in its process. You can create custom Status labels to show in frontend and backend under **Stores->Settings->Order Status**

You can also code this to add statuses and use the new status in your order creation :

```
use Magento\Sales\Model;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\StatusFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Status;
class ... {
    protected $_statusFactory;
    protected $_status;
    public function __construct(
        StatusFactory $statusFactory,
        Status $status,
...)
    {
        $this->_statusFactory = $statusFactory;
        $this->_status = $status;
}

public function ... (){

$customorderstaterep = $this->_status;

$customorderstate = $this->_statusFactory->create();
$customorderstate
->setData('status', 'NewStatus')
->assignState(Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING)
->setData('label', 'NewStatusLabel');

$customorderstaterep->save($customorderstate);

}
}
```

This you need to link with an existing State (processing/pending/...). This is a way to have your own Labels but still keep the process of Magento.

I recommend not to adjust the State that Magento is using as this can have effect on functionality. Instead link it with an existing State.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. I'm not sure of what you mean by "not to adjust adjust the State that Magento is using", as I'm talking specifically about linking states and statuses that are not linked by default in Magento. If possible, could you please elaborate on the issues that could arise when setting a status and a state that aren't linked by default?

Comment: You can link a status to an existing state with ->assignState like i said. But i ment its not the intention that you create your own state as far as i know but create a status and link that to an existing state

Comment: notice the difference between a State and a Status

Comment: Once payment is done, the order status showing as "Processing" by default but I wanted to show as "Pending/New" similar to "Cash On Delivery".  If I want to set the order status as "Pending/New" programmatically once the order is placed. What should I do? Please advise.

Comment: @Vinayagam you can view all the possible states in Magento\Sales\Model\Order. Just replace the correct constant instead of STATE_PROCESSING to what you want and assign the right 'status' string to the setData clause.

Comment: This answer is about how to create a state. Not assign them. You can just use $order->setState(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT) and then save your $order